# UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit with margin

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

Hello I want to aspectfit an image in a uiimageview but want to also have some padding for tha t image instead of it fitting to width or to height. I also don't want to scale the image because it loses quality if I try to zoom in later.

Any idea? Been looking around and cant find anything.

Comment: If you don't want to scale the image, you don't want to use AspectFit, or are you only wanting to avoid scaling the image larger than the original?

Comment: Aspect fit is ok but just wanted some padding around. For example, if the image is fitting toheight. i.e the image y = imageview y , then  i would like the image y to be equal to imageview y + 10. I think the only solution is to add another subview which Wain mentioned below. Kind of wanted to avoid that.

Comment: Frequently the solution to automatic layout (or S&S layout) is to add padding views :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either set the border width on the image view or add the image view as a subview of another view but with an inset frame.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried the border view before but that doesn't prevent the image from drawing from y = 0 if it is fitting to height. This means the border covers the image.

Comment: The best way is to just add the extra subview. Kind of annoying but works.